# How to add multple animation to same object using blender's python API

Tags: python, animation, keyframes

I have a 3d rigged model which requires animation to be patched in however, the animations are present in an external file (A json file which has the frame data stored) and I want to apply those animations using python. I'd like to know:

1. How can I create multiple animations for the same object using blender's python API
2. How can I apply those animations for one particular animation name (After achieving solution to Number

Comment: Can you add some or all of the json file so I can get a sense of the source information?

Comment: @MartyFouts it is not a JSON file but a binary file which I'll be reading on runtime, the binary file contains data for each bone for T second (Example: It'll contain 5 discrete frame data for all the bones with its position and rotation along with the time)